# Flutter bottom overflowed by

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

All of my bottomappbar code and everything about how my code looks is available below. No matter what I did, I couldn't fix it, I need help :/ All of my bottomappbar code and everything about how my code looks is available below. No matter what I did, I couldn't fix it, I need help :/All of my bottomappbar code and everything about how my code looks is available below. No matter what I did, I couldn't fix it, I need help :/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIF36.png)

```
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
      color: Colors.grey[900],
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 8.0),
        child: Container(
          height: 90, // İstediğiniz yüksekliğe göre bu değeri ayarlayabilirsiniz.
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Column(
                children: [
                  Image.asset('assets/bomba.png', width: 50, height: 50), // Boyut ayarları
                  SizedBox(height: 1), // İkon ile metin arasındaki mesafe
                  Text(
                    '$_jokerCount',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white), // Metin stili
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                _eliminateTwoWrongChoices();
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Image.asset('assets/doktor.png'),
              onPressed: () {
                _selectCorrectAnswer();
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Image.asset('assets/süre.png'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _remainingTime += 15;
                });
              },
            ),

            IconButton(
              icon: Image.asset('assets/skip.png'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SpinningWheel(jetonSayisi: widget.jetonSayisi, jetonAzalt: widget.jetonAzalt,) //The getter 'jetonAzalt' isn't defined for the type 'QuestionPage'.
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Consider Using FittedBox

try to use FittedBox and it will fit  the availaible space for you , but it will decrease the size of the image if needed, also consider using expanded for responsive layout,

```dart
BottomAppBar(
        color: Colors.grey[900],
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 8.0),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 90,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                FittedBox(
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: const Column(
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.abc),
                        Text(
                          '2',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.abc),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.abc),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.abc),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much but it didn't work :(

Comment: can you please provide more detaills on whats the output looks for you

Comment: consider using expanded in the column also

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the height in your Container is set to 90. In this case you can increase the height, An alternative way is to change the icon size or spacing between the icon and the text inside of your Column or decrease vertical padding of your BottomAppBar.

Comment: Changing the height value did not cause any change. If I can adjust the amount of space above the bottomappbar, or rather the exact location where the PNG will stay, I think there will be no problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).